# stack overflow on overriding lazy val in scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

I have trimmed my code down to the following.  I am confused why I am getting a stack overflow between the two filter methods (one in my trait and one in my superclass)

```
object TestingOutTraits {

  val TestHandler = new Object with MySuper with MyTrait {
    override lazy val createdFilter = {
      "second part"
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val result : String = TestHandler.start()
    System.out.println("result="+result)
  }
}

trait MySuper {

  protected def filter: String = {
    "first part to->"
  }

  def start() = {
    filter
  }
}

trait MyTrait { self: MySuper =>

  lazy val createdFilter = {
    "override this"
  }

  protected override def filter: String = {
    self.filter + createdFilter
  }
}
```

This is scala 2.9.  Any ideas what is going on here?

EDIT:
The stack trace makes no sense on how it jumps back and forth too(I should have included it in original post)...

```
at MyTrait$class.filter(TestingOutTraits.scala:34)
at TestingOutTraits$$anon$1.filter(TestingOutTraits.scala:4)
at MyTrait$class.filter(TestingOutTraits.scala:34)
at TestingOutTraits$$anon$1.filter(TestingOutTraits.scala:4)
```

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Trace it with a debugger.  You'll most likely see control jumping back and forth between two methods, and then you'll have your answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did that and it makes no sense since it jumps between TestHandler class definition which does NOT have this method and the MyTrait.filter method and at least correctly never hits the MySuper.filter since it is overridden.

Comment: This is somehow related on how scala instantiate variables in traits, somewhere there was a discussion about this which at the moment I can't find.

Comment: The `TestingOut` in your trace is obviously your anonymous class. It has a `filter` method from the mixin, which just calls to the implementation, which is `MyTrait$class`. That's how they do mixins.

Comment: FWIW, debuggers can be unhelpful when jumping around synthetic code, IMHO. Also when tracing through closures, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call `self.filter` in `MyTrait.filter` invokes itself, leading to infinite recursion that blows the stack.

Instead, have `MyTrait` extend `MySuper`, and use `super.filter`:

```
trait MyTrait extends MySuper {
  lazy val createdFilter = {
    "override this"
  }

  protected override def filter: String = {
    super.filter + createdFilter
  }
}
```

Comment: hmmmmm, I thought using self was the proper way to call the super when mixing in a trait to avoid calling yourself?  If not, what is self for then?  as I can call other methods without self.  self was to resolve conflicts, or wasn't it?

Comment: also notice in my post, the linearization causes a filter method to end up in my created object....I would think that shouldn't be the case?  That seems like a bug and I have read on other linearization bugs related to lazy val specifically (still trying to piece stuff together).

Comment: hmmmm, I should note that MyTrait is not really a MySuper and makes more sense as an optional mixin.  I can't find a way to call the MySuper.filter from the trait however which is quite frustrating.  I read that this used to be allowed and perhaps is no longer allowed?

Comment: selfies: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/modular-programming-using-objects.html#i979629307-1

Comment: I think OP is overthinking a bit. See my answer for decoupled stackable traits.

Comment: @DeanHiller Your object gets a `filter` method because it inherits from traits with `filter` methods. You are not seeing a Scala bug, the self-type annotation is always the same as `this` but with a different type. The purpose of the self-type annotation is mostly to restrict what types the trait can be mixed into.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
trait MySuper extends Filtered {

  protected def filter: String = {
    "first part to->"
  }

  def start() = {
    filter
  }
}

trait Filtered {
  protected def filter: String
}
trait MyTrait extends Filtered {

  lazy val createdFilter = {
    "override this"
  }

  protected abstract override def filter: String = {
    super.filter + createdFilter
  }
}
```

then

```
  val nope = new MyTrait { }  // correctly DNC
```

and the OP

```
  val TestHandler = new MySuper with MyTrait {
    override lazy val createdFilter = {
      "second part"
    }
  }
```

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.5

Comment: You mean `new MyTrait with MySuper`.

Comment: @DanielDarabos by "nope" I meant to say it does not compile, which is desirable.

Comment: This is good. I suspected OP really wanted `abstract override`, but I didn't want to write it up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know why the infinite recursion though this seems like a linearization bug in scala and I am not sure how to work around it yet either :(.

hmmmm, so it turns out the compiler is sticking a filter method in my new Object for some reason.  I found this out with the print:mixin on scalac like so

```
    $ scalac -Xprint:mixin TestingOutTraits.scala
      [[syntax trees at end of mixin]]// Scala source: TestingOutTraits.scala
    package <empty> {
      final object TestingOutTraits extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
        private[this] val TestHandler: MySuper = _;
        <stable> <accessor> def TestHandler(): MySuper = TestingOutTraits.this.TestHandler;
          def main(args: Array[java.lang.String]): Unit = {
          val result: java.lang.String = TestingOutTraits.this.TestHandler().start();
          java.this.lang.System.out.println("result=".+(result))
          };
          def this(): object TestingOutTraits = {
          TestingOutTraits.super.this();
          TestingOutTraits.this.TestHandler = {
            new anonymous class TestingOutTraits$$anon$1()
          };
          ()
          }
          };
          abstract trait MySuper extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
          def filter(): java.lang.String;
          def start(): java.lang.String
          };
          abstract trait MyTrait extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject { self: MyTrait =>
            def createdFilter(): java.lang.String;
            override def filter(): java.lang.String
          };
          abstract trait MySuper$class extends  {
          def filter($this: MySuper): java.lang.String = "first part to->";
          def start($this: MySuper): java.lang.String = $this.filter();
          def /*MySuper$class*/$init$($this: MySuper): Unit = {
            ()
          }
          };
          abstract trait MyTrait$class extends  { self: MyTrait =>
            def createdFilter($this: MyTrait): java.lang.String = "override this";
            override def filter($this: MyTrait): java.lang.String = $this.$asInstanceOf[MySuper]().filter().+($this.createdFilter());
        def /*MyTrait$class*/$init$($this: MyTrait): Unit = {
          ()
        }
        };
        final class TestingOutTraits$$anon$1 extends java.lang.Object with MySuper with MyTrait {
        override def filter(): java.lang.String = MyTrait$class.filter(TestingOutTraits$$anon$1.this);
        def start(): java.lang.String = MySuper$class.start(TestingOutTraits$$anon$1.this);
        override def createdFilter(): java.lang.String = "second part";
        def this(): anonymous class TestingOutTraits$$anon$1 = {
          TestingOutTraits$$anon$1.super.this();
          MySuper$class./*MySuper$class*/$init$(TestingOutTraits$$anon$1.this);
          MyTrait$class./*MyTrait$class*/$init$(TestingOutTraits$$anon$1.this);
          ()
        }
        }
```